# How to determine that BizTalk has completed processing a message

Tags: automated-tests, biztalk

We are writing automated system tests for a BizTalk application, but have a problem determining when we can execute the test's verification. We need to be sure that BizTalk has completely processed the message, or message processing has timed out, before the verification.

```
[Test]
public void ReceiveValidTaskMessageTestShouldBeLoggedInMessageLog()
{
    // Exercise            
    MsmqHelpers.SendMessage(InboundQueueName, ValidMessage);

    // Verify
    Assert.That(() => GetMessageCount("ReceiveError"), Is.EqualTo(0).After(1000));
    Assert.That(() => GetMessageCount("Receive"), Is.EqualTo(1).After(1000));
}
```

The last two lines check for the existence of a copy of the message in a table in an sql server, one table for successful message, one table for errors.

The problem here is that immediately after sending the message we verify that no message has been placed in the error table. But if BizTalk has not yet processed the message, then that assertion will pass even when it should fail.

What we need is something like this:

```
[Test]
public void ReceiveValidTaskMessageTestShouldBeLoggedInMessageLog()
{
    // Exercise            
    MsmqHelpers.SendMessage(InboundQueueName, ValidMessage);

    // Verify
    Assert.That(() => PendingMessages, Is.EqualTo(0).After(1000));
    Assert.That(() => GetMessageCount("ReceiveError"), Is.EqualTo(0));
    Assert.That(() => GetMessageCount("Receive"), Is.EqualTo(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Herein lies the problem with automated integration testing.

Such testing is *evidence-based*, which is reflected in your test's assertions; you are looking for evidence that processing has taken place by check a database.

Similarly, in order to know that processing has finished, you are seeking some evidence that this has happened. For example, theoretically you could run queries against BizTalk message box database to check the state within.

However, BizTalk doesn't lend itself well to this kind of probing as it has not been built with testing in mind (one of it's weaknesses). I certainly wouldn't know how to go about doing this.

A couple of approaches worth considering:

1. Wait a "reasonable" amount of time before performing the database check to allow BizTalk to finish processing the message.
2. Have BizTalk output a log file (or some other evidence) just before processing completes which you can check before checking the database.

Even though the approach is limited automated integration testing is incredibly valuable.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to be notified when a record appears in either of those tables and pass/fail the test as appropriate. You could use a rudimentary infinite loop to continuously poll the tables, or a more elegant solution would be to use events - see the [event handler delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) for more details.